# Why is this set of solutions compact?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, compactness

[This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06712) paper, in theorem 1.1, page 3, states that if $k < 0$, then the following set is compact: $$\mathfrak{F}^-_k=\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: 3\leqslant x \leqslant y \leqslant z \leqslant \frac{1}{2}xy, \ x^2+y^2+z^2-xyz=k \}$$
Can someone explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you perhaps mean $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{Z}^3$. The "generic" makes me a bit a bit suspicious, over the reals the precise value of $k$ shouldn't play such a big role. I would probably also help to speficy where in the paper they claim this.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven In the paper they do consider $(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3.$ However, it seems the authors define $\mathfrak{F}_k^+$ slightly differently, see theorem 1.1. The definition in this post appears to mix the sets in parts (i) and (ii).

Comment: @Stahl Thanks, I fixed it.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Done!

Comment: Can you prove the set is closed?  Can you prove the set is bounded?

Comment: @GEdgar I can prove that the is closed, but I can't prove that it's bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After dividing the inequality by $xyz$, we get
$$ \frac{x}{yz} + \frac{y}{xz} + \frac{z}{xy} -1 = \frac{k}{xyz}. $$
Using the inequalities in the definition of our set, we obtain
$$ 1 = \frac{x}{yz} + \frac{y}{xz} + \frac{z}{xy} + \frac{-k}{xyz}
\leq \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\vert k \vert}{z}
\leq \frac{1+\vert k \vert}{z} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2}
=\frac{1+\vert k \vert}{z} + \frac{5}{6} . $$
Thus, we get
$$ \frac{1}{6} \leq \frac{1+\vert k \vert}{z} $$
and hence
$$ z \leq 6 (1+\vert k \vert). $$
This implies that our set is bounded. You said that you already showed that it is closed (we can just write
$$ \mathfrak{F}_k^{-} = F^{-1}([0;\infty)\times [0;\infty) \times [0;\infty) \times [0;\infty) \times \{0 \}) $$
where $F: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5, F(x,y,z) = (x-3, y-x,z-y, xy/2- z, x^2+y^2+z^2-xyz =k)$)
and therefore by the Heine-Borel theorem it is compact.

**Added:** It might be worth noting that the sign of $k$ does not matter, the very same argument applies if $k$ is positive.